# Dynamic add button show wrong value jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 0;
    var j = 1;
    $("#add").click(function(){
        ++i;
        var c = i + j;
        $("#dynamicpre").append('<div class="dynamicfields mb-5"><h5>Track:' + c + '</h5></div>');

    });
    $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){  
        $(this).closest('.dynamicfields').remove();
    });  
</script>
```

In the above question I am simply append a value through `c` variable. Now, What happen here when I click on add button it show `Track:2` but when I click on remove and click again on add button then it show `Track:3` but I want to show `Track:2`. So, How can I do this? Please help.

Thank You

Comment: What should happen if you add 1, 2, 3, remove 2, then click Add?

Comment: Should it fill in the missing 2, or add 4?

Comment: then it doesn't show 2 it start from 4 @Barmar

Comment: No it doesn't fill missing @Barmar

Comment: When you're removing, check if the one you're removing is the last one. If it is, subtract 1 from `i`.

Comment: check my answer

Comment: Can you please show element `.remove-tr`. Is it created dynamically or what?

Answer (score 0):

you have to -1 the value of "j" on removing function and also create a remove button at the end only and remove the last div on remove button click then it will work fine :

```js
         var i = 0;
        var j = 1;
        $("#add").click(function(){
            ++i;
            var c = i + j;
            $("#dynamicpre").append('<div class="dynamicfields mb-5"><h5>Track:' + c + '</h5></div>');
    
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function(){  
         if(j>=1){
           i --;
         }  
         $(".dynamicfields:last-child").remove()
          
        });
```

```html
<input value="add" type="button" id="add" />

<div id="dynamicpre">
hammad


</div>

 <input value="remove" type="button" class="remove-tr" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: As I check If I have 1,2,3 and I remove 2 then it show 1,3,3

Comment: try now i have updated my answer with the html

Comment: i've tested it in the js fiddle its working fine

Answer (score 0):

From your `.remove-tr` click code it seems that you will be having `.remove-tr` element inside `.dynamicfields` div then only your `$(this).closest` would work, so I have added `.remove-tr` button dymanically.

Check comments for explanation.

```js
$("#add").click(function() {
  // default track value
  let c = 1;
  // get last dynamicfields's h5 element inside #dynamicpre
  let lastAdded = $("#dynamicpre .dynamicfields h5:last");
  // check if there is any dynamicfields is there? if yes then only get track number
  if (lastAdded.length) {
    // get track number from last dynamicfields from its text
    // get track text and replace Track: with empty value and convert it to number
    c = 1 + Number(lastAdded.text().replace("Track:", ""));
  }

  // append new div with remove button
  $("#dynamicpre").append('<div class="dynamicfields mb-5"><h5>Track:' + c + '</h5> <input type="button" class="remove-tr" value="remove" /> </div>');

});

$(document).on('click', '.remove-tr', function() {
  $(this).closest('.dynamicfields').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="add" value="add">
<div id="dynamicpre">
</div>
```